# How to multiply the (j,i)'th of a matrix with column i in another matrix to produce j matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices of sizes j x i and m x i. What I try to do, is to multiply the i'j element of matrix1 with column i in matrix2. This would give me a vector of size mx1. When this is done for all i elements for a given row j in matrix1, I want to put together these i vectors to a matrix of dimensions mxi. Repeat for all j so that we end up with j mxi matrices

An example might help:

```
a1 <- c(0.5,0.2,0.2)
a2 <- c(0.2,0.8,0.4)
b1 <- c(3,4)
b2 <- c(1,2)

b <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
a <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 3)

b[,1] <- b1; b[,2] <- b2
a[,1] <- a1; a[,2] <- a2
```

Here I want to multiply a[,1] with b[1,1] and then a[,2] with b[1,2] to get

```
> new.m.j <- cbind(a[,1]*b[1,1], a[,2]*b[1,2])
> 
> new.m.j
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.5  0.2
[2,]  0.6  0.8
[3,]  0.6  0.4
```

I want to do this for all j columns in matrix1 to get a list of j matrices.

I can obviously do this with a loop, which would be rather simple. However, I try to teach myself to use more apply (and s/l-apply), and I am pretty sure you could solve this in that way.

Comment: And how do you use  that with an lapply-function?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `new.m.j` is simply `t(t(a)*b[1,])`. You can then use this structure within `lapply` to produce the list of matricies you want.

```
lapply(seq(nrow(b)), function(j) t(t(a)*b[j,]))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.5  0.2
[2,]  0.6  0.8
[3,]  0.6  0.4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  2.0  0.4
[2,]  0.8  1.6
[3,]  0.8  0.8
```